# Why does it take much longer time for worldcat REST API to return response while using urllib2 python library than while using browser?

Tags: python, rest, urllib2

I am using worldcat python package which uses worldcat open REST API and fetches book data using search query and other parameters.Basically it does this -

```
self.response = urllib2.urlopen(_query_url).read()
```

where _query_url is the url made of base url and some parameters such as search string, no of records per page etc. By using timeit package I found out it took 18-20 seconds for every call to the API.

However if I make that request from the browser it takes just 3-4 seconds.What is causing the delay in the python lib.Is it normal? How can I make API requests faster in python?

Answer (score 0):

my lucky guess is to use custom headers - they might have some kind of protection or whatever.

try:

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Type": "text/html;charset=utf-8"
}

r = urllib2.Request(_query_url, None, headers)
self.response = urllib2.urlopen(r)
```

Anyway, i love using [python 'requets'](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), why not give them a try. Simple and stable. Apart from some SSL-keys problem but thats another story.

Comment: Wojcicki - I applied your method but the result is same.I am getting response in 15-20 seconds

Comment: Hello again,

i've acquired sandbox key and tried the following code: [external link](http://pastebin.com/arZiVASV) (too long for reply) which results in  

`Avg time: 0.45305, all tests: [0.636, 0.538, 0.422, 0.408,  
0.48, 0.452, 0.446, 0.424, 0.474, 0.45, 0.419,  
0.428, 0.422, 0.45, 0.42, 0.488, 0.434, 0.419, 0.429,0.422]`  
  
I'm really sorry, but for me it seems to work correctly. Of course it might depend on the query. Or sandbox is just fast. I've got no idea :(